# Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have an error in my SQL syntax "Query cannot be parsed, please check the syntax of your query. (ORA-00904: "RENTED": invalid identifier)". How to solve this problem??

```
SELECT area,
       status,
       price_le,
       location

from stores
WHERE status = rented 
ORDER BY location;
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have an actual table field called `rented` that you want to compare to, you'll need to single quote it to have it be a string;

```
SELECT area, status, price_le, location
FROM stores WHERE status = 'rented' ORDER BY location;
```

Comment: @user3609435 - please remember to [up-vote useful answers and accept the best solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Read more [on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251078/266304). Of course all three current answers say much the same thing so you'd need to pick one to be the 'best', which is entirely up to you; but this one was right first...

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about your database schema - I assume you intended to test status against the string 'rented' in your where clause. To do that you need to surround rented in single quotes.

```
SELECT area, status, price_le, location
FROM stores WHERE status = 'rented'
ORDER BY location;
```

Comment: Single quotes for a string literal; you're trying to compare it to a (mixed-case, quoted) identifier, not a string value. This will get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

SELECT area, status, price_le, location
FROM stores WHERE status = 'rented' ORDER BY location;